# jQuery - How to Log file on error

Tags: jquery, logging, error-handling

I have a project in Javascript, and it is working fine... People are already using it, and sometimes it shows erros... I dont want users to see the error. I would like to log in some File.txt the erros, or send them by email, with details about the error( type of error, url, ... ). I want something like this:

```
try{
   //code
   var a = 1 + 1;

}catch(e){
   Log( File.txt, e.toString(), url );
 //or
   Mail( dest@exemple.com, e.toString(), url );
}
```

is it possible? is there some library to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Java script is a client side language, and runs in a sandbox where browsers won't let you do anything. So there is no built in function that allows it. The best thing you can do is wrap log or email in some kind of module, and make a web request to do the emailing/logging that you would like. Although I'm not sure why you'd want to do this, since any errors should be handled by your front-end code.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var Log = function (url, data) {
    return $.post(url, {
        json: JSON.stringify({
            "err": data
        })
    }, "json")
};

try {
    //code
    var a = abc + 1;

} catch (e) {
    //  Log( File.txt, e.toString(), url );
    //or
    //  Mail( dest@exemple.com, e.toString(), url );
    Log("File.php", e.message)
    //    .then(

    // function (data) {
    //    console.log(data.err)
    // }, function (jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //    console.log(errorThrown)
    // })
};
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/gu1gmsug/

Comment: console.log is only available when the debugger window is open, which in turn will cause errors in production, you may want to check before you log.

Comment: How would this help me? where it sends the log?

Comment: @Thiago At function `Log()` , `url` would be `File.php` , where `data` sent by `$.post()` logged to `File.txt`. Necessitates creating `File.php` to process post , and `File.txt` to append `data` to.

Comment: Would the file be permanent , or temporary (available for viewing while browser open) ? Thanks